# Disable react-native-reanimated globally for tests

Tags: react-native, react-native-reanimated, react-native-reanimated-v2

We'd like to disable `react-native-reanimated` animations for tests based on a context variable, especially when we do UI snapshot tests to avoid flakes. For example, if there's a loading spinner, we don't want variations of its spinning animation lifecycle to be diffed and considered a change in the UI.

We've tried to wrap `useAnimatedStyle` in our own hook to pass the `updater` as `()=>({})` if we're in a test env, but there are a variety of issues that we're  calling a JS from the UI thread:

```
const useLibraryAnimatedStyle = <T extends AnimatedStyle>(
  updater: () => T,
  deps?: DependencyList | null,
) => {
  const { areAnimationsEnabled } = useLibraryGlobals();
  const enabled = useSharedValue(areAnimationsEnabled);

  useEffect(() => {
    if (enabled.value !== areAnimationsEnabled) {
      enabled.value = areAnimationsEnabled;
    }
  }, [areAnimationsEnabled, enabled]);

  return useAnimatedStyle(enabled.value ? updater : () => ({}), deps);
};
```

**Error:** Tried to synchronously call anonymous function from a different thread

[image]

Wrapping updater as a worklet didn't seem to work, because the `useAnimatedStyle` does that anyway according to the Reanimated documentation.

Answer (score 0):

Turned out that I did have to add `"worklet"` to the updater i was passing in:

```
const animatedStyles = useLibraryAnimatedStyle(() => {
  "worker";

  return {
    transform: [{ rotateZ: "100deg" }],
  };
});
```

vs what you normally pass to `useAnimatedStyle`

```
const animatedStyles = useAnimatedStyle(() => ({
    transform: [{ rotateZ: "100deg" }],
});
```